# How to access the secrets on Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to assign **a Gituhub Secrets** value to an environment variable, but I can't.

I have saved my Google API Key in a Github Actions Secrets.
I wrote a Github Actions workflow to first assign the secrets value to `GOOGLE_API_KEY`, then create .env file, and write `GOOGLE_API_KEY = $GOOGLE_API_KEY` to the file.

However, the value is returned as blank, when I try to access the secret value by `${{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}`.

[image]

if it's shown as "***", I guess the action actually get the secret value and it's just filtered, but in my case it's just nothing.

Could anybody give me a clue as to how to access a Secrets value?

My (simplified) GitHub Action is as follows:

```
name: Run rspec

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  rspec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GOOGLE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.1.3
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Database create and migrate
        run: |
          cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
          bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
          bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

      - name: Create dotenv file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo GOOGLE_API_KEY = $GOOGLE_API_KEY >> .env

      - name: Run rspec
        run: |
          bundle exec rspec
```

I can get a Actions Variables by ${{ vars.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}, if I save the API key in Actions Variables, which I know I shouldn't.

Comment: Is `&{{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}`a typo? You should use `${{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I corrected my question. I use `${{ secrets.GOOGLE_API_KEY }}` in my workflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found that a reusable workflow needs to inherit secrets from the calling workflow. So all I needed to do was adding `secrets: inherit` to 'deploy.yml' which calls this rspec workflow.

```
jobs:
  rspec:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/rspec.yml
    secrets: inherit
```

Comment: It didn't indicate from your source that you use reusable workflow. It seems you oversimplified your code.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test and it works with your workflow

```yaml
on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  rspec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        GOOGLE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}

    steps:
        - name: display
          run: |
            echo "$GOOGLE_API_KEY" |  awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=" "

            touch .env
            echo GOOGLE_API_KEY = $GOOGLE_API_KEY >> .env

            cat .env | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=" "
```

Here is display:

[image]

Could you check in the way how I did it. (Please revoke your API key once you finish your tests)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work with my case. It returned just `G O O G L E _ A P I _ K E Y   =`  and still looks my workflow cannot access the secrets value...

Comment: Are you sure you set it as repository secret? Or maybe environment secret?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found this workflow needed to inherit secrets from calling workflow and it worked!